# How to config git to pull from http and push through ssh in one 'remote'?

Tags: git, authentication, git-push, git-pull

Pulling from http to escape authentication(so I don't need to type password if I'm not using ssh.keygen).

Pushing through ssh with authentication.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diferent default remote for git pull and git push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916845/diferent-default-remote-for-git-pull-and-git-push)

Comment: The title of this question is good for someone who doesn't think to use the term "default".

Comment: @jww: Right, I think that's what I meant 7 years ago.  The title is worded such that this question is easier to find than the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [`git-config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> `remote.<name>.url` The URL of a remote
>   repository. See git-fetch(1) or
>   git-push(1).
>
> `remote.<name>.pushurl` The push URL of
>   a remote repository. See git-push(1).

Try setting the former to an `http:` url and the latter to a `git+ssh:` (or just `git:`) url?

Comment: Thx!!
just edit .git/config file, change it like this:
 [remote "origin"]
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 url = http://git.yoursite.com/your_project.git
 pushurl = git@git.yoursite.com:/home/git/repositories/your_project.git

Comment: @Amber - Can you provide an example of this? I'm not quite following Tsung's example in the comments.

Comment: @jww I have added an example with the exact git config command, and the resulting git configuration result.

Answer (score 16):

Original answer, for  **push through ssh in one 'remote'**: this applies only to *one* repo, the current one:

If you have a `git remote -v` which returns an https URL for "`origin`", you can type:

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl git@github.com:aUser/aRepo
```

Or rather:

```
git remote set-url --push git@github.com:aUSer/aRepo
```

As [noted here](https://github.com/git/git-reference/issues/5#issuecomment-4106859):

> It is not functionally different, as `set-url` internally ends up just calling config. But `set-url` will complain if you mistype the command part "`git remote set-url --push`", whereas git config will silently accept mistyped options, but fail to actually set the remote's url.

See **[git-reference](http://git.github.io/git-reference/remotes/#remote-update)** (here adapted):

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/schacon/git-reference.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/schacon/git-reference.git (push)

$ git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:schacon/git-reference.git

$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/schacon/git-reference.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:schacon/git-reference.git (push)
```

---

In the context of the bounty, [jww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww) adds:

> I want this to apply to all of github.com, and not just my repos

Then `git remote` is not the answer.

Only [`url.<base>.pushInsteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtpushInsteadOf) would apply to *all* repos:

> Any URL that starts with this value will not be pushed to; instead, it will be rewritten to start with , and the resulting URL will be pushed to. I

So:

```
 git config --global url."git@github.com:".pushInsteadOf https://github.com/
 # or
 git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com/".pushInsteadOf https://github.com/
```

I mentioned that option in 2014 in "[Git: how to get the public, read-only git:// URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22295808/6309)".

The `--global` option will make that applied to *all* repos, not just the current one.

---

From [jridgewell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323767/jridgewell)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553270/how-to-config-git-to-pull-from-http-and-push-through-ssh-in-one-remote/51687862#comment127175719_51687862) and [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jridgewell/d5c22e6add8b372c9671d710bdd39d3e/raw/230ad8da6b5c29f60cba8ed5a7739cfe46ff6de9/gistfile1.txt):

In order to always pull from HTTPS and always push through SSH, the following will work:

```
 git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
 git config --global url."git@github.com:".pushInsteadOf https://github.com/
 git config --global url."git@github.com:".pushInsteadOf git@github.com:
```

This uses `insteadOf` to rewrite SSH into HTTPS for pulls. It also uses `pushInsteadOf` (the first) to rewrite HTTPS to SSH for pushes. And it uses a `pushInsteadOf` (the second) to ensure that SSH is used for pushes if the original remote URL was SSH.

The second `pushInsteadOf` is important.
Git uses the first push URL written, and it applies `pushInsteadOf` before `insteadOf`.
By rewritting an original `git@github.com:` to `git@github.com:`, we prevent the `insteadOf` from rewritting SSH to HTTPS for pushes.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. In my case, I want all GitHub pushes to occur with SSH, and all pulls to occur with HTTPS. Everything else should use HTTPS for pull and push. [Here is my gitconfig](https://pastebin.com/4hbVhxSF). When I try to add `[pull https://github.com]` it still uses SSH for the pull. Other twiddling just seems to break Git. I got the `url/InsteadOf` from another Stack Overflow Q&A some time ago but have not been able to advance it to HTTPS pull and SSH push.

Comment: @jww First, remove the insteadOf: that will be clearer

Comment: @jww second, try cloning the repo as https, then use `git remote set-url --push git@github.com:aUSer/aRepo` within the local clone.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Can you show me a working gitconfig that accomplishes it? It is painful for me to work with the git command line. It is a lot easier to copy/paste a gitconfig.

Comment: @jww It is less risky to type the command. Just copy-paste `git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:yourUser/yourRepo.git` and you are done.

Comment: Thanks, will do. How do I remove the `yourUser/yourRepo` part from the command? I want this to apply to all of github.com, and not just my repos.

Comment: @jww test it first on your repo to see if that is working (and that will give you a working gitconfig). Simply edit your command to replace yourUser/yourRepo by your GitHub username and remote repo name.

Comment: @jww " I want this to apply to all of github.com, and not just my repos. " I have edited the answer with an alternative that does apply to all repos.

Comment: @jww Does my last edit (from 5 days ago) answer the bounty?

Comment: @jww So... that did not answered the bounty, I guess?

Comment: I got the answer from the Git mailing list. I needed a solution for the entire site, and not just one repo at a time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using the following. It will force push URLs to be rewritten to use SSH (yes, it rewrites SSH to SSH), and pulls to use HTTPS.

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
  insteadOf = "git@github.com:"
[url "git@github.com:"]
  pushInsteadOf = "https://github.com/"
  pushInsteadOf = "git@github.com:"
```

Comment: @jridgewell Thank you. What would be the `git config` command to use for that? You can edit directly the answer to add your own command/configuration.

Comment: The suggested edits queue is full, so I'm not able to edit directly. I've copy-pasted my edits to a [gist], if you'd like to update your answer.

[gist]: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jridgewell/d5c22e6add8b372c9671d710bdd39d3e/raw/230ad8da6b5c29f60cba8ed5a7739cfe46ff6de9/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @jridgewell Thank you so much, much clearer now. I have included your edit in the answer, with proper attribution.