# Git: how to get the public, read-only git:// URL

Tags: github

I'm needing to give my `http://github.com/user/project` as a git://  URL, and it needs to be read-only and public.  My `http://github` repo is public at the moment, but I can't figure out to generate or get my git:// URL.

Thank you for reading. :)

Comment: It works for me by simply replacing `http://` with `git://` in the URL given by the github web interface. So it's `git://github.com/user/project` with an optional `.git` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

While simply replacing `https//` by `git://` should work, the fact is git will use the port 9418 to communicate (I mention it in "[Which is faster, ssh or git protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248848/6309)").

That port is often blocked (as shown in "[`git://` protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4891527/6309)"), which is why only `https://` and `ssh://` are shown in the GitHub GUI.

Note that [this gist](https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747) illustrates that you could push from `git://`, but push over (for instance) `ssh://` with the **`pushInsteadOf`** config setting:

> You can clone everything over git://, but tell Git to push over HTTPS.

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
```

> Likewise, if you want to clone over git:// or HTTPS, but push over SSH:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
```