# How to set default push repository in Git?

Tags: git, default

How can I make `git pull` from `git@source.com:...` repository and `git push` to `git@target.com:...` repository by default?

In Mercurial I create `.hg/hgrc` with the following content:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@source.com/...
default-push = ssh://hg@target.com/...
```

What is the way to set the same default behaviour in Git?

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916845/different-default-remote-tracking-branch-for-git-pull-and-git-push

Comment: Incidentally, it's unusual (though not impossible) to push via `git://`.  As the man page notes, "disabled by default, as there is no authentication in the protocol (in other words, anybody can push anything into the repository, including removal of refs). This is solely meant for a closed LAN setting where everybody is friendly."

Comment: @torek, fixed links to be more real.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the Git remote 'push to' default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801147/changing-the-git-remote-push-to-default)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In git the remotes are in the `[remote "<name>"]` sections.  When you clone something, the initial remote is `origin`, so that's usually the one to use.  The fetch URL is the `url` and the push URL is the `pushurl`.  You also need a `fetch` line (or several lines) to bring over branch names.

Typically, then, you will see, in `.git/config`, something like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://...
```

Change the url to `git://source` and add `pushurl = git://target` (you can do this with `git config` commands, or `git remote`, or just run `git config -e` to bring up your regular editor on the file).

Branches need to have an "upstream" set (in two parts, `remote` and `merge`) to cause them to "track" a "remote branch".  Typically since the remote is named `origin` you set `branch.master.remote` to `origin` and `branch.master.merge` to `master`, for instance.  (When you create a local branch based on a remote branch, in any even slightly modern version of git, it will set it up as "tracking" for you.)

Generally you should also configure `push.default` to something other than the git 1.x default value; `simple` is probably best for avoiding accidents.

Note that if you're used to Mercurial, `hg pull` is most similar to `git fetch`, not `git pull`; `hg pull -u` is somewhat closer to `git pull`, but I recommend training yourself to use `git fetch` instead of `git pull` (even if you're not used to Mercurial, actually :-) ).  It also takes some adjusting to the different ways hg and git handle branches (hg has one single global name space for branches, and another single global one for bookmarks; git has per-remote "remote branch" name spaces, and local branches are more like hg local bookmarks.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This `remotes` jargon is unusual, but ok. I also don't use branches much, so this is kind of extra info for me right now. Forgot to say - `pushurl = git://target` helps!

Comment: In git, you're always forced to use the remote and local branches and named "remotes", as that's just how it works.  Hg's single branch name-space means that if you just use branch `default` (and maybe even a few more), things are a lot easier, but they turn out to be much less flexible.  The good stuff is bad and vice versa, depending on your needs; that's life! :-)

Answer (score 6):

It's almost the same in git. Each repository has a `.git/config` file and there should be some thing like this in it:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = git://path/to/your/repo
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

You don't have to add those manually, there's quite a few commands that help you. A good start is the [Git SCM Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

To set the default fore one single branch you can simply type: `git branch --set-upstream-to YOUR_REMOTE_NAME/YOUR_BRANCH_NAME`(when using git >= 1.8.0)

Comment: Thanks for the hint - Git SCM definitely helps - I can now see effective settings with `git remote -v`. Regarding this answer, I can't see how to set `default-push` here. I am not sure I am proficient with branch stuff in Git.

Answer (score 4):

I combined hints from @torek, @klaustopher (thanks for the answers) and duplicate link from @Mali to make it easier for people from Mercurial background to find the answer.

To add `default-push` in Git, use:

```
$ git config remote.origin.pushurl git@github.com:yourname/project.git
```

To check current setup:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:user/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:yourname/project.git (push)
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer. The others are TL;DR and don't really answer the question.