# Git fork and pstream sync with existing branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

1. I fork a master repo on Bitbucket.com?
2. I create a new branch called "branch-A" on my copied repo from #1.
3. I switch to "branch-A"
4. I point "upstream" to the master repo. I did a "git fetch upstream"
5. I ran "git merge upstream/master"

It is strange to me at at step 5, git merge DID NOT apply the merge to the master branch on my local repo, instead, it applied the merge to "branch-A". Is this the proper behavior of git? Or I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

> It is strange to me at at step 5, git merge DID NOT apply the merge to the master branch on my local repo, instead, it applied the merge to "branch-A".

Yes, it is the expected behavior since, in step 3, you switched to `branchA`.
[`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) merges in the current branch.

To apply the merge to master, swtich back to master *before* step 5

```
git checkout master 
git merge upstream/master
```

An alternative approach would be to:

- [set local `master` to track `upstream/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309) (meaning by default it pulls from `upstream`)

  ```
  git branch --set-upstream master upstream/master
  ```
- [set the push url to your remote fork `origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30488025/6309):

  ```
  git config remote.pushDefault origin
  ```

That way, a simple `git pull` (after `git checkout master`) would always pull from `upstream`, but a `git push` would push to your fork `origin`.