# Different default remote for push and pull

Tags: git, git-remote

Can I set it so that pull always pulls from upstream and push always pushes to origin unless specified otherwise.

P.S. - I don't want a different push and pull (set-url) for a specific remote but rather different default remotes.

Edit - Check Postscript before reporting it duplicate.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @iBug Check PostScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different default remote (tracking branch) for git pull and git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916845/different-default-remote-tracking-branch-for-git-pull-and-git-push)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE** - just realized you said *default* remote

You can set `remote.pushDefault` to the remote you want to push to.  Branch tracking settings would still determine the default behavior of pull I believe.

**Original answer** which works per-branch

You can set the config option `branch.<name>.remote` to the remote you want to pull from, and set `branch.<name>.pushRemote` to the remote you want to push to.