# pull from master while pushing to another branch

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a workflow that with auto-merge to master.

For that, I am working locally on a branch called `dev-oshai`, and want to push always to that branch on the server with: `git push`

When I want to pull changes I want to always pull them from `master` (CI will auto-merge changes to master from all developers).

For that I am using the command `git pull --rebase origin master`

More context and details here: https://medium.com/@OhadShai/git-mono-branch-workflow-pre-tested-commits-4b34949310ad

Is it possible to configure git that the default pull branch will be `origin master` so that `git pull` will work without always specifying the branch?

Comment: i dont see a way to have the mix of pushing to the default and pulling from another default. you can set the upstream like usual but that would be for pulling and pushing...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916845/different-default-remote-tracking-branch-for-git-pull-and-git-push see if that helps

Comment: Whenever you call git pull it will always pick up your current branch. I don't think there is a way to define default branch on pull either you can make an alias of this command in your .bashrc file so that you don't have to write the command again and again...

Comment: @L_Church this will set the different repositories for the same code. But the above question is to set different branches for pull and push.

Comment: ah well there goes my ideas i already +1 so this can get out

Comment: You can use ElpieKay's answer, but I recommend getting out of the habit of running `git pull` at all, ever. Just run `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`. The whole question at this point kind of goes away: you will use `git rebase origin/master` and `git push origin HEAD:dev-oshai` or similar (you can leave the upstream completely unset).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = <repo_url>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "foo"]
        url = <repo_url>
        push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/dev-oshai
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        pushRemote = foo
        merge = refs/heads/master
        rebase = true
```

This way, when in branch `master`, `git pull` is equivalent to `git pull origin -r master:master` and `git push` is equivalent to `git push foo master:dev-oshai`. The urls of `origin` and `foo` are the same.

Besides `true`, `branch.master.rebase` can be assigned `preserve` or `interactive`.

> When preserve, also pass --preserve-merges along to git rebase so that
>   locally committed merge commits will not be flattened by running git
>   pull.
>
> When the value is interactive, the rebase is run in interactive mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to change the behaviour for `git pull` completely. (except creating an alias)
But you can make it a bit less to type.

First, set up pull to always rebase in your gitconfig.

```
[pull]
    rebase = true
```

Next, you can do a little hack. Add your remote as a new local remote, so you have it twice.
For example master.

```
git remote add master https://example.com/repo.git
```

Fetch all branches

```
git fetch master
```

And set the upstream of `dev-oshai` to master of the new remote.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=master/master
```

Now you can pull from master with

```
git pull master
```

If this really is a good idea or more confusing than helpful is your decision.